# xp_cmdshell bcp wont save file

Tags: bcp

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT lastconnectip FROM RF_USER.dbo.tbl_UserAccount" queryout "C:\test.txt" -T -c'
```

The command above runs, the output:

```
NULL
Starting copy...
1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file. Total received: 1000
NULL
1158 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1      Average : (1158000.00 rows per sec.)
NULL
```

But no file is actually written. what am i missing?  The user does have full rights (sysadmin) SQL 2008 R2.

Also alternative way to use NETSH in sql query/trigger would work aswell instead of the one  above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably look for the file on the client computer. `xp_cmdshell` executes on the server, so look for `C:\test.txt` on the SQL Server machine.

Answer (score 2):

For sysadmins, [`xp_cmdshell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) runs the command as the SQL database engine service account.

Make sure that account has been granted write permissions on the target location.